# passing value into shortcode via Scratch - not working

Tags: hugo, hugo-shortcode

I'm trying to set a value in `.Scratch` in a page template, and to read it in a shortcode used on that page, but having no luck.

The content has:

```
{{< my_shortcode arg="something" >}}
```

The page template (in the theme) has:

```
{{ .Scratch.Set "foo" "bar" }}
```

The shortcode (also in the theme) has:

```
the value of foo is {{ .Scratch.Get "foo" }}.
```

But the rendered output has:

```
the value of foo is .
```

I've tried several variations on this, including prefixing `.Scratch` with a `$` in both contexts, and also by trying to access it from `.Page.Scratch` in the shortcode file. In all cases, I get an empty return. I'm using version v0.75.0-DEV. Any pointers greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand, HUGO pages and shortcodes do not share contexts thus data exchange is limited. This leads to a quite strange situation:

- in page template `{{ .Scratch }}` is the page's scratch;
- in shortcode template `{{ .Scratch }}` is the shortcode's local scratch;
- in shortcode template `{{ .Page.Scratch }}` is the page's scratch but it does not share context with the page, so it differs from the first one.

The `{{ .Page.Scratch }}` in shortcodes can be used to share data between all shortcode's instances on a single page, but it can't be used to share data with page's template.

Share data between shortcodes on a page to insert JS only once:

```
{{ if le (.Page.Scratch.Get "mermaidInserted") 0 }}
  <script src="{{ "js/deps/mermaid.min.js" | relURL }}"></script>
  {{ .Page.Scratch.Add "mermaidInserted" 1 }}
{{ end }}
```